# product classification problem , model should show product category but showing numerical value instead

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, text-classification

train.py

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.cluster import MiniBatchKMeans
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import joblib
import numpy as np
nltk.download('stopwords')

stop = stopwords.words('english')
porter = PorterStemmer()


def preprocess_data(text):
    ''' The function to remove punctuation, stopwords, and apply stemming'''
    words = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]", " ", text)
    words = [word.lower() for word in words.split()
             if word.lower() not in stop]
    words = [porter.stem(word) for word in words]
    return " ".join(words)


# Read the data
df = pd.read_csv('ifound_cat.csv')
df['Description'] = df['Description'].apply(preprocess_data)

# Flattening and Encoding the Labels
df['MainCategory'] = df['Category'].apply(lambda x: x.split(' > ')[0])
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
df['EncodedCategory'] = label_encoder.fit_transform(df['MainCategory'])

# Split the data
X = df['Description']
y = df['EncodedCategory']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)

# Vectorize the data
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=5, ngram_range=(1, 2))
X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = vectorizer.transform(X_test)

# Apply MiniBatchKMeans for faster clustering
kmeans = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=100, random_state=42)
auto_generated_labels = kmeans.fit_predict(X_train)

# Create a new DataFrame for the auto-generated labels
auto_generated_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'auto_generated_category': auto_generated_labels})
# code is created by *********JUNAID AHMED MIRANI******
# Concatenate it with the original DataFrame
df = pd.concat([df, auto_generated_df], axis=1)

# Fit the label encoder on all possible labels
all_possible_labels = np.arange(kmeans.n_clusters)
label_encoder.fit(all_possible_labels)
# Train a classification model (e.g., Logistic Regression)
classifier = LogisticRegression(max_iter=1000)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
score = classifier.score(X_test, y_test)

# Save the model
joblib.dump(classifier, 'testing/category_classifier.joblib')
joblib.dump(vectorizer, 'testing/tfidf_vectorizer.joblib')
# Save the KMeans model and label encoder
joblib.dump(kmeans, 'testing/kmeans_model.joblib')
joblib.dump(label_encoder, 'testing/label_encoder.joblib')
# The line joblib.dump(label_encoder.classes_, 'testing/label_encoder_classes.joblib') should be placed
# in your train.py file, right after you fit the LabelEncoder.
#  This line is saving the classes of the LabelEncoder after it has been fit on the training data.
joblib.dump(label_encoder.classes_, 'testing/label_encoder_classes.joblib')

print(f'Model Accuracy: {score}')
```

prediction.py

```
import pandas as pd
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
import joblib
from joblib import load
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import nltk

nltk.download('punkt')

MODELSPATH = 'testing/category_classifier.joblib'
TFIDF_VECTORIZER_PATH = 'testing/tfidf_vectorizer.joblib'
LABEL_ENCODER_PATH = 'testing/label_encoder.joblib'
DATAFILE = 'ifound_cat.csv'

stop = stopwords.words('english')
porter = PorterStemmer()

# Load the trained TF-IDF vectorizer
vectorizer = load(TFIDF_VECTORIZER_PATH)

# Load the trained label encoder
label_encoder = joblib.load(LABEL_ENCODER_PATH)

# print(label_encoder.classes_)


def load_model():
    '''Loading pretrained model'''
    model = load(MODELSPATH)
    return model


def preprocess_data(text):
    ''' Applying stopwords and stemming on raw data'''
    words = word_tokenize(text.lower())
    words = [word for word in words if word not in stop]
    words = [porter.stem(word) for word in words]
    return " ".join(words)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = pd.read_csv(DATAFILE)
    model = load_model()

    # Preprocess the description column
    data['Description'] = data['Description'].apply(preprocess_data)

    # Convert descriptions to TF-IDF features
    description_features = vectorizer.transform(data['Description'])

    # Make predictions using the input features
    predictions = model.predict(description_features).astype(int)

    # Transform numerical labels to category names
    predicted_category_names = label_encoder.inverse_transform(predictions)

    # Add predicted category names to the DataFrame
    data['Predicted_Category'] = predicted_category_names

    # Save the data with predicted category names
    data.to_csv('result.csv', index=False)
```

can you tell me what is wrong with this model , as i am running it after getting description as input it should give me the product category but it is instead giving the me the encoded number value

can you tell me what is wrong with this model , as i am running it after getting description as input it should give me the product category but it is instead giving the me the encoded number value

Comment: Please share some rows from `'ifound_cat.csv'`. Also, it seems what you need should be done via the inverse_transform function. This needs to be shared too.